# How to print on windows form application label

Tags: c++, winforms, user-interface

how to print the node data (ie: curr->room) in label of windows form application in c++

my Node includes 'time' and 'room' variables of string

```
    bool found = false;
    node* curr = l.first;

    while (curr != 0)
    {
        if (curr->course == "$")
        {
            found = true;

                cout << "Time: " << curr->time << endl;
            cout << "Room: " << curr->room << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (found == false)
        out->Text = "No Free Slots Found!";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give us a bit more information about your application to be able to properly help you.

In Winforms, a Label control has a Text property just like most other types. To display your Node data in the Label, make a string and set the Label's Text to that string:

```
myLabel.Text = string.Format("Time: {0}  Room: {1}", curr->time, curr->room);
```